# How to reflect a private constructor out of multiple private constructors

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

I've got some factory classes I am reading from the hard drive.

Those factories have no public constructors, they have 2 private constructors:
One constructor for reflection and one constructor for creation.

This code worked when there was only one public constructor, but as it is it throws a strange exception:

```
public static void setupCalculators()
{
    String calculatorsBasePackage = "feature.calculators";
    ArrayList<String> res;
    try
    {
        res = ReflectionHelper.getClassNamesFromPackage(calculatorsBasePackage);

        for (String file : res)
        {
            file = file.replace("/", "");
            Class<?> klass = Class.forName(calculatorsBasePackage + "." + file);

            //The exception happens on the following line:
            Constructor<?> c = klass.getDeclaredConstructor((Class[])null); 


            c.setAccessible(true);
            ICalculatorFactory calculatorFactory = 
                (ICalculatorFactory) c.newInstance((Object[])null);

            addCalculator(file.replace("_Calculator", ""), calculatorFactory);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException | SecurityException | 
           IllegalArgumentException | InstantiationException |  
           IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException |  
           NoSuchMethodException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the class to be examined:

```
private POS_F_Calculator()
{
}

private POS_F_Calculator()
{
}    
private POS_F_Calculator(StructureRepresentation representation)
{
    this.representation = representation;
}

@Override
public ICalculator newCalculator(IRepresentation representation)
{
    return new POS_F_Calculator((StructureRepresentation) representation);
}
```

**And here is the exception thrown:**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: feature.calculators.POS_F_Calculator$1.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at feature.CalculatorHandler.setupCalculators(CalculatorHandler.java:37)
    at driver.Driver.main(Driver.java:36)
```

I'm trying to figure out what I've done wrong.  What does this exception mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of research:
One of the classes had a Runnable implementation in it, and was compiled to an anonymous class
POS_F_Calculator$1

Solution:
Since there is a very specific naming I will be discarding classes that do not use that specific naming.

Answer (score 0):

> Constructor c = klass.getDeclaredConstructor((Class[])null); /* here comes the exception */

Here you are saying the constructor you want has zero arguments. The constructor you *actually have* has one argument:

> private POS_F_Calculator(StructureRepresentation representation)

So the call should read:

```
Constructor<?> c = klass.getDeclaredConstructor(StructureRepresentation.class);
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that I haven't copied both of the constructors. my bad. I've edited the question.

Comment: Answer is unchanged. You haven't specified the constructor argument list correctly.

Comment: Sorry, but you're wrong. The list is specified correctly, and after I disregard inner classes and anonymous classes (those that have the $ sign upon compilation) all works great.

Answer (score -1):

```
public Constructor<T> getDeclaredConstructor(Class<?>... parameterTypes)
                                  throws NoSuchMethodException,
                                         SecurityException
```

[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29)

> (Class[])null

. How can you cast **null** to **class** !? when null is not a class

Comment: Well this is one of the things I've seen suggested and accepted in stack overflow, and it is not a syntactic error since java compiles and runs it...it doesn't work with this part of code and without it either...